# Is there a usage like "help do something"?

Tags: american-english, complementation

It is the article I saw on the bbc news few months ago.

> He stood by a pledge, made in a speech sunday in Cairo, for funding to **HELP BUILD** "human capacities,infrastructure and so on for those  blablabla"

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly common.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=help+build%2Chelp+to+build&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chelp%20build%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chelp%20to%20build%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 3):

You can use an infinitive either with to or without to after the verb "help", without any difference in meaning. So it's correct to say "...... for funding to help build/to help to build......".